# (SOLVED) Python subtraction operator not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I'm creating a GUI implementation of roulette in python using PyQT6. However, when I was creating a function to stack similar bets, I began encountering an error with the subtraction

The first time I place a $10 bet on 36, it subtracts $10 from my wallet, as expected. However, I go to place another $10 bet on 36, and it subtracts no money. The next time, it adds $10. After that, it adds $20, $30, $40 and so on. Upon debugging, the amount fed into the function is correct, but the function to subtract money is not working

```
self.t.players[0].subtract_money(
    self.BetAmountBox.value()
)  # Remove money
```

`self.BetAmountBox` is just a spinbox (single), where the users enter their bet amount. The `subtract_money()` function is contained within a separate player class, defined as:

```
def subtract_money(self, amount: int) -> None:
        self.balance -= amount  # Subtract the money
```

This problem only appears when stacking bets, and does not occur when just placing regular bets

I tried to debug several times, as well as using the -= operator in the controller code itself, but none of those seemed to yield anything. However, upon debugging, I noticed that sometimes the player wallet would be $1000 according to the debug panel even though I had placed bets and subtracted money before that, though this could be an unrelated error.

Comment: I guarantee that the subtraction operator works correctly. The problem must be the parameters. Try putting `print(self.balance, amount)` in the `subtract_money()` function, to see what it's doing.

Comment: I just found out what it was. There was another function that was refunding the bet before the updated bet was created :P

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that.